# debugging on a device with your application preloaded

Tags: android, preload

Is there a way you can develop on a device that has your application preloaded on it?  I have tried changing the name of the application, but that affects a lot of files, and you couldn't realistically develop that way (changing all the names before checkin and then cheanging them back aftewards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can sign your app with the same signing key as was used for the copy of your app in the device's firmware, having a higher `android:versionCode` should allow you to install and test the updated app. Leastways, that's how apps like Google Maps work as I understand it, where the firmware ships one but updates come by way of the Android Market.

If, however, you cannot sign your app with the same signing key, that won't work, and you have no real choice but to either:

1. Root the device, delete the firmware copy, possibly un-root (de-root? dis-root?) the device, then use it normally, or
2. Refactor your app as you describe

Comment: how do you specify the keypass and storepass?

Comment: @user645402: IIRC, you define them when you create the keystore.

Comment: Hm...  I'm confused.  I have a debug keystore and a release keystore.  I just copied my release keystore over my debug keystore and tried running on the phone with the preload, but it didn't work (there was the red x in eclipse and it wouldn't run).  when the automated build runs, it "signs" the application...  it uses -keypass and -storepass with the release keystore -- so... do I need to sign the application before I can debug it on the device (that already has a preload on it)?

Comment: @user645402: Unless you are the device manufacturer, you don't have the keystore you need.

Comment: @user645402: AFAIK. You really should be asking these questions of the device manufacturer who preloaded your app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the project from command line into a different package name(other than the one used by the preloaded app)...
Check this link for further details:
  http://elinux.org/Android_aapt
 http://blog.uncommons.org/2010/07/19/building-two-versions-of-the-same-android-app 
 especially the aapt --custom-package where you can specify the new package name for your app...
 --
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for debugging on a phone are set out in the guide topic [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

Comment: @user645402 - Perhaps I misunderstood. Your question title said you wanted to debug on a device. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: debug on a device that has my application preloaded on it.

Comment: @user645402 That's exactly what the guide topic discusses.

Comment: see selected answer.  do you know what "preloaded" means?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Enable debug mode on the device, and connect the device to a computer using a USB, then you can look at the logs (assuming that your app uses logging). You do **not** need to root the device.

I general turn off logging on APKs that will actually be used (I have a custom wrapper for console.log that I can turn off with a global). In a case like that, you can set an Easter Egg in your app that would allow the user to turn logging on if they know the appropriate password, etc.